# VIM: Move to beginning of IF condition

Tags: vim

Let's say my code is

```
if (...) { //How can VIM reach to this IF statement
     if (...) {
     }
     if (...) {
     }
     // { { { {
     //10000 more lines...

     | My Cursor is here now. I want to go the "parent" IF statement

     //10000 more lines
}
```

I tried using "[{" but this would not work if there's comments with "{" which interrupts it.

Answer (score 1):

The "matchit" plug-in can help here, it provides better matches that are able to recognize and skip matches inside comments.

The "matchit" plug-in is actually distributed with Vim starting with Vim 8.0, but you need to enable it explicitly. See [`:help matchit-install`](https://vimhelp.org/usr_05.txt.html#matchit-install) for details. But, in short, just add this line to your vimrc file:

```
packadd! matchit
```

Once the plug-in is activated, you can use the [`[%`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/doc/matchit.txt#L35,L36) motion to move to the `{` at the top-level "if". (Note that "matchit" uses a separate motion `[%`, it doesn't override `[{` which continues to move to the `{` inside the comment.)

Note also that you need to have filetype detection and syntax highlighting enabled for this feature to work properly, since "matchit" actually uses the syntax highlighting groups to detect whether a match is inside a comment.